# Who have done the act laughing in the sentence "The girl came to her mother laughing"?

Tags: participles

**The girl came to her mother laughing.**

Here who have done the act laughing? I mean whether it *the girl* or *mother*

Answer (score 2):

> Here who have done the act laughing?

Joke: **she** did the act of laughing :)

@ColleenV explained better than I could, how it is a joke:

> Because both the girl and the mother are "she", someone could be a [wisenheimer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wisenheimer) and answer "she" did the laughing.

---

> **The girl came to her mother laughing.**

Joke aside, the sentence is 100% ambiguous. Different people will understand different things. Without any modification, it is impossible to tell which one of the two was laughing.

---

Disambiguation

To underline that **the girl was laughing**, the sentence can be arranged like:

> The **laughing** girl came to her mother.

or

> The girl, **while laughing**, came to her mother.

---

To underline that **the mother was laughing**, the sentence can be arranged like:

> The girl came to her **laughing** mother.

or, using more words:

> The girl came to her mother, **while the mother was (still) laughing**.

Comment: I saw a girl eating rice. Here the act eating rice is done by the girl;not by me,is it? So Why  laughing in the ssentence *I saw the girl laughing* is done by me? Thank you

Comment: "I saw a girl eating rice." - is almost equally ambiguous, the same like any sentence following that pattern.

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely the girl who is doing the laughing. The sentence could be restructured to more clearly indicate the subject:

> The girl, laughing, came to her mother.
>
> The laughing girl came to her mother.
>
> The girl **was** laughing **as** she came to her mother.

Edit: Bamboozled again. English is definitely the most user-friendly language :^)

Comment: It could've only been different if the girl had come home to her mother laughing.