# "who" refers to what here?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> The boy pushed his brother who was wearing a white short.

"who" refers to what in the sentence above?

If "his brother" was followed by a comma, would the refrence of "who" changes?

Thank you

Comment: In your *exact* example, it's syntactically unambiguous that ***who*** refers to the immediately preceding noun *(**[his] brother**)*. If I change it to, say, *I saw the boy pushing his brother who was wearing white shorts*, it becomes ambiguous as to whether it's the boy or his brother who's wearing shorts. I don't know how to explain the formal syntax rule making *my* example different to yours, but there's no doubt in my mind that difference is real (it's not just a matter of more or less likely interpretations).

Comment: To be honest, I have wanted to state this ambiguous version which you have suggested but couldn't remember the exact structure of it. Another thing, would a comma indicate poor grammar in my original example? Thank you for contributing valuable information.

Comment: Including the comma (which simply reflects a ***pause*** in real *spoken* language) identifies what follows as a "non-restrictive" relative clause (which just provides additional information about "his brother"). Without the comma, it's a *restrictive* clause (the boy has multiple brothers; the one he pushed was ***specifically** the one wearing white shorts*).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Who was wearing a white short"* is a **relative clause** of *"his brother."* (similar to an adjective but afterwards and it looks like a sentence) In English, relative clauses, (which start with who, whom, which, that and any relative pronoun I might have missed,) normally come immediately after the noun they modify. The starting pronoun (if considered a pronoun) always refers to the immediately preceding noun and it is the subject of the relative clause.

[http://glossary.sil.org/term/relative-clause](https://glossary.sil.org/term/relative-clause) seems to think that "The plumber arrived who we had called earlier." (where who=the plumber) is a good sentence. In this case, notice how, even though relative clause is not **immediately** after the noun it modifies, there is no other noun between them.

It is also possible to add another noun after the first word of a relative clause. That new word will the become the subject of the clause, and the initial pronoun will become the object. Thus, in:
*The boy pushed his brother who I hate.*
Contains the relative clause *"who I hate"*, where *I* is the subject of the the relative clause, and *who* (referring to the brother) is the object. Strangely, this type of clause always has OSV (object subject verb) word order.

(Also, I think you meant shirt not short)

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "who" refers to the brother.

If there was an intention to refer to "the boy", the sentence could have been formulated:

> The boy who was wearing a white short pushed his brother.

Comment: I won't actually downvote, but I disagree completely with ***more likely*** in your first sentence. There's absolutely no possibility that ***who*** could refer to the boy doing the pushing in OP's example. Syntactically, it's not in the least ambiguous (and including a comma or not makes no difference to this).

Comment: In this other post (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204900/who-have-done-the-act-laughing-in-the-sentence-the-girl-came-to-her-mother-laug/204950) the "laughing" is definitely ambiguous. But in this case (with the white short), I would 95% understand "the brother", not "the boy". I could say that "the boy" and "who" are too far away, but it will not stand in the other case (linked earlier). However, "The boy pushed his brother wearing a white short." will make it definitely ambiguous, even to me. I have no idea why :)

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood you? You mean I should say "definitely" instead of "more likely"?

Comment: I think you did misunderstand me. Yes, I mean you should say "definitely" instead of "more likely". It's not "95% likely" that ***who*** refers to the brother - it's **100% certain** (because of the exact *syntax* - nothing to do with "probable real-world context", "intended meaning", or anything like that).

Comment: OK, thanks. I will update.

Comment: Your revised text *Someone should make some significant effort to understand X* isn't "natural" English, but if I was forced to "interpret" it, I'd have to say it means *A person would need to make significant effort to justify assigning meaning X to this text.* Which is ***still not true**!* No matter how much "effort" you make, you ***cannot*** interpret the text that way. There is ***no ambiguity whatsoever***.

Comment: 1. And there is the answer to my not-yet-asked question: how "native" does my English sound? :)  2. For you and me, there is no ambiguity. However, there are many posts, even here on ELL, where complete rubbish makes sense for some people, even without making any effort. But overall, after better analysis, I think it's best to follow the KIS strategy. 3. I will surely not force you to "interpret" :)

Comment: Most of what you've written sounds perfectly "natural" to me (i.e. - your English is pretty damn good! :) If it didn't, I wouldn't have wasted your time and mine pointing out anything specific that *didn't* sound natural. I do realize that because you yourself are not a native Anglophone, it's at least *possible* that you (and other learners here on ELL) might think there's at least ***some*** ambiguity in OP's example. But to a native speaker there could *never* be any ambiguity with that exact text. (KISS rules! That's plain unadorned ***never***, not ***almost never**!* :)