# Confused use the comma

Tags: sentence-construction

I know the brother of Ram, who loved Rani.
I know the brother of Ram who loved Rani. 
Are the sentences same in meaning?
In the first one we've  used  comma and in the 2nd one we haven't used comma.
What are the meanings of them?

Comment: Who loved Rani?

Comment: I already answered this question previously: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/207973/89027 It is not OK to ask the same question twice. It is OK to edit the original question to add more details. Adding a comma does not change anything, the sentence is still equally ambiguous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of the relative pronoun who](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/207973/use-of-the-relative-pronoun-who)